# Actual invocation has different arguments Unit Presenter

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I create a unit test for my Presenter. My Presenter implements Listener callback if successfully load data from API (use Interactor):

**PresenterTest.java**

```
public class MainContactPresenterTest {
    @Mock LoadContactInteractor loadContactInteractor;
    @Mock ApiService apiService;

    @Mock LoadContactView loadContactView;
    @Mock ContactRepository contactRepository;
    @Mock LoadContactInteractor.OnLoadDataFinishedListener listener;

    @InjectMocks MainContactPresenterImpl presenter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getContactLists() {
        // given
        // when
        presenter.fetchRemoteContacts();

        // then
        Mockito.verify(loadContactInteractor).onLoadData(listener);
    }
}
```

Here is my Presenter:

```
public class MainContactPresenterImpl implements MainContactPresenter,
        LoadContactInteractor.OnLoadDataFinishedListener {

    private LoadContactView loadContactView;
    private LoadContactInteractor loadContactInteractor;
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @Inject
    public MainContactPresenterImpl(LoadContactInteractor loadContactInteractor,
                                    @NonNull LoadContactView loadContactView,
                                    ContactRepository contactRepository) {
        this.loadContactView = loadContactView;
        this.loadContactInteractor = loadContactInteractor;
        this.contactRepository = contactRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccessLoad(List<Contact> contacts) {
        loadContactView.saveDataToLocalStorage(contacts);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorLoad() {
        loadContactView.dismissProgress();
        loadContactView.showErrorMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void preCheckCacheData() {
        if (contactRepository.getContactCount() == 0) {
            // Load contacts from Server
            fetchRemoteContacts();
        } else {
            fetchLocalContacts();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void fetchRemoteContacts() {
        loadContactView.showProgress();

        loadContactInteractor.onLoadData(this);
    }
}
```

But when I ran test, I got the mocking parameter in `verify` not match.
I got my presenter that have to be an argument. Not the listener.

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
loadContactInteractor.onLoadData(
    listener
);

Actual invocation has different arguments:
loadContactInteractor.onLoadData(
   fanjavaid.gojek.com.contacts.presenter.MainContactPresenterImpl@1757cd72
);
```

How to handle that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a mock...

```
@Mock LoadContactInteractor.OnLoadDataFinishedListener listener;
```

...and then you don't use it ever again and act suprised when `verify` tells you, that it wasn't actually used. Why? Of course it wasn't used, since you never use it anywhere, so how should your classes know to use that mock object?

Your `MainContactPresenterImpl` does not **use** an `OnLoadDataFinishedListener` as an external dependency (then your could perhaps inject it via `@InjectMocks`), it **is** itself such a listener and thus mocking another listener makes no sense here.

In other words, `MainContactPresenterImpl` has no `OnLoadDataFinishedListener` `field`, so Mockito is of course not capable of injecting something in this non-existing field. For something like this to work, you would need to add such a field and then use the content of that field when calling your `onLoadData` method.

The only invocation of your method is here...

```
loadContactInteractor.onLoadData(this);
```

And what is `this` in that context? It's the `MainContactPresenterImpl` object that contains the method, in other words, your `presenter`.

So, what will work is...

```
Mockito.verify(loadContactInteractor).onLoadData(presenter);
```